# How to use winsock2.h in C#?

Tags: c#

How to use winsock2.h and linking ws2_32.lib in C#? Like in C++

```
#include <winsock2.h>  
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
```

Comment: You would use p/invoke, but any reason you don't want to use the comprehensive socket support in the BCL?

Comment: Forget Ws2_32.dll just use `System.Net.Sockets`

Comment: Yes, I have a code in C++ that I will translate in C#, but I'm biginer in C#, so I don't have what to I do. Now it's nice, I used System.Net.Sockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think he means something like this...
You need to using

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
```

The term "using" is equivalent to the include statements in c++. Also you will need to add a reference to the library you are using. Cheers!

Comment: System.Net.Sockets is similiar library to winsock but not exactly same as Winscok2. Some functions work differently.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [complete winsock wrapper written in .NET](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4043&lngWId=10) It is written in VB.NET and you can download source code. Basically you need PInvoke native functions